# Bernoulli's inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction

I use induction to prove that

$(1+x)^r \geqslant 1+rx$ when $r>1$ and $x\geqslant-1$

I have done the second step in the proof, but not the first one. Many solutions on the internet use r=1 because their $r$ was not bounded , but here $r>1$. I suppose I can use $r=2$, but then I can't see if the inequality is true or not.

Comment: So prove it when $r\geq1$.  It's always okay to prove a stronger statement.

Comment: What is the second step?

Comment: @saulspatz But should I not stick to how the task bounds r ?

Comment: @FareedAF The second step is to prove that the inequality is true for r=k+1

Comment: If you prove the statement is true when $r\geq1$ you have also proved it true for $r>1$.  No one can possibly say you've not done the task.

Comment: He who can do the more can do the less…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As they said if you showed it for $r \ge 1$ then ofcourse it is true for $r>1$.

But if you want to prove it for $r=2$, you just simply do $(1+x)^2=1+2x+x^2 \ge 1+2x$ since $x^2\ge 0$ for any real number $x$.

Comment: Ohh, I feel stupid now. Of course! Thank you so much!